# Angular DI and inheritance: injecting extensions of a base service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, inheritance, dependency-injection

I have a base service and two inhering services:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BaseService {
  foo(src?: string){
    return `speaking from ${src || 'BaseService'}`;
  }
}


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SomeService extends BaseService {
  foo(){
    return super.foo('SomeService')
  }
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AnotherService extends BaseService {
  foo(){
    return super.foo('AnotherService')
  }
}
```

I wish to inject them in some component and retrieve instances of the three separate classes:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <p>Who's there?</p>
            <p>{{ base }}</p>
            <p>{{ some }}</p>
            <p>{{ another }}</p>

        </div>
    `,
})
export class App {
    base: string;
    some: string;
    another: string;

    constructor(base: BaseService, some: SomeService, another: AnotherService) {
        this.base = base.foo();
        this.some = some.foo();
        this.another = another.foo();

    }
}
```

Instead, I get three instances of the same class (HTML output):

```
Who's there?

speaking from BaseService

speaking from BaseService

speaking from BaseService
```

- Why doesn't this work?
- Why are SomeService, AnotherService and BaseService not unique tokens for Angular DI?

It seems that putting

```
...    
{ provide: SomeService , useClass: SomeService },
{ provide: AnotherService , useClass: AnotherService },
...
```

in the providers will make it work.

- Why is this explicitly needed?

A plnkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/BvmppLHRbFbz9CFZ

Comment: this is simply the OOPs Concept

Comment: care to explain if its so simple? ;)

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. If you think you have an answer to OPs question, add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeService` and `AnotherService` inherit the decorator metadata from `BaseService`, so angular injects an instance of `BaseService` in their place.

This is dangerous, as calling any instance member from either `SomeService` or `AnotherService` which isnt inherited from `BaseService` will trigger a run-time error.

The simplest way to archive the behavior you are looking for, would be to inherit from a common abstract base class, with no decorator:

```
export abstract class AbstractBaseService {
  foo(src?: string) {
    return `speaking from ${src || 'AbstractBaseService'}`;
  }
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BaseService extends AbstractBaseService {
  foo() {
    return super.foo('BaseService');
  }
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})
export class SomeService extends AbstractBaseService {
  foo() {
    return super.foo('SomeService');
  }
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AnotherService extends AbstractBaseService {
  foo() {
    return super.foo('AnotherService');
  }
}
```

I [modified your plnkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/aRosUmxSXgWkkTym?preview) to test this approach.

Comment: Thanks  a lot! Care to elaborate on "This is dangerous ... trigger a run-time error." ?

Comment: Using your original approach, if you define `anotherFoo()` in `AnotherService` and invoke it in the component constructor, an exception will arise.

Comment: Ah, yeah, clearly. Cause there are actually no instances of `AnotherService` floating around at that point. Also, I think it is weird that "`SomeService` and `AnotherService` inherit the decorator metadata from `BaseService`" (although I guess you're right). I guess this has to do with how `emitDecoratorData` works under the hood. Shouldn't derived classes have their own metadata?

Comment: I recall reading that some time ago in the angular source, sadly Im unable to find it. Until then, dont consider my answer some sort of "absolute truth" :D

Comment: As we speak, I was actually diving into the source code to figure out how this metadata inheritance works precisely, but it confuses the hell out of me. If you rediscover the relevant lines of code, do let me know!